# CPU Spikes and SBBoD

Tags: mamp-pro

I moved five different sites into MAMP Pro 4.0.6 recently, and now the program is running very sluggishly. I get periodic spinning beach balls anytime I touch the interface, and Activity Monitor shows MAMP %CPU shooting up to 75 and even 100 + shortly after. Once I get a site actually open, it seems to run fine in the browser. It's just the MAMP interace has ground to a halt.

I thought this might be a port conflict, but moving away from 80/3306 to program defaults has not solved the problem.

I also thought this might have something to do with using PHP 7.0.12, so I moved back to 5.6.27, but this has had not impact either.

Can anyone suggest other ways to troubleshoot this? I've looked in my logs and have found nothing overly suspicious except for reference to a two.crt files left over from a dev server SSL install. I removed these, but I'm not sure if this would have any impact.

Thanks.

-- Lee

Comment: I've been working on several different WordPress sites, and I've had no problems using them via the browser. But the MAMP Pro interface continues showing the SBBOD every time I touch the interface, and Activity Monitor continues to show spikes in the 70% to 110% range.

Comment: Changed permissions on five migrated sites to 777 and now MySQL will not start. What is going on here? Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's time for a complete uninstall/reinstall. Anyone have any suggestions beyond the instructions here?https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215198206-How-do-I-do-a-complete-uninstall-and-re-install-of-MAMP-PRO-

Comment: Have decided to uninstall/reinstall. No other choice, apparently.

Comment: Five times today, I have tried to install MAMP, and after it gets to IFPKInstallElement, I get a message that authorization has failed, even though I've type in the exact same authorization earlier in the process:

Couldn't instantiate install client: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=100 "Authorization is required to install the packages." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization is required to install the packages.}

Any ideas as to what is causing this? Corrupted file, perhaps?

Comment: Cannot get past authorization problem above. Can someone, anyone, with a clue about MAMP provide some insight? I've been using this program for four years with no problems whatsoever, and I cannot get this reinstall to work.